# Can numba accelerate numpy functions that are already vectorized?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numba, eigenvector

I want to use numba and cuda to parallelize the diagonalization of some number of hermitian matrices on a grid.
Let H be my matrix of the dimension 1000 x 1000 x 64 x 64.Thus, I want to get the eigenvectors and values of one million 64 x 64 matrices. 
Numpy's eigh function from the linalg package already does a pretty good job. 
If I call `linalg.eigh(H)` it is already vectorized and distributed over the cores of my computer.

On the nVidia website they show an example like this:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import vectorize

@vectorize(['float32(float32, float32)'], target='cuda')
def Add(a, b):
  return a + b
```

But in the example the function is not already vectorized. Basically, I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to speed up an already vectorized function with numba any further without any use of CUDA.
2. If I would like to put this on some GPU cluster with numba, is it as easy as they suggest in the example?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to speed up an already vectorized function with numba any further without any use of CUDA.

No.

And the function you mentioned, `linalg.eigh`, isn't "vectorized" (in the numpy or Numba sense of the word) or even written in Python. As per the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eigh.html), it is just a wrapper around Lapack routines `syevd` and `heevd`, which will be pre-compiled C or Fortran code in an external library. The only reason why you see it utilize multiple cores is because your version of numpy has been built against a multithreaded implementation of Lapack (probably [Intel MKL](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl), if you are using the Anaconda version of numpy). A standard numpy will be compiled and linked against the system Lapack, which is often the [netlib implementation](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/), and that is not multithreaded and would not appear "vectorized", as you describe it.

> If I would like to put this on some GPU cluster with numba, is it as easy as they suggest in the example?

No it is not easy. It is impossible.

Comment: So there is no way to use numpy for computation on a cluster? I find it way more elegant than if I would call some C function with OpenMP or MPI from my python code.

Comment: @Pickniclas: That isn't what you asked. You asked if you could run `linalg.eigh` on a GPU cluster (which I assume means using the GPUs on that cluster) using Numba, That is impossible. And numba doesn't automagically support distributed computing environments either. Obviously there are ways to use numpy on a distributed memory system. But not using bare Numba, which is what you asked