# Full diagonalization NumPy vs SciPy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I have to make use of diagonalization routines to obtain all eigenpairs of a Hermitian complex matrix. I am a bit limited by performance since I need to repeat the operation thousands of times and my matrices are roughly of 8000x8000. I have created a little comparison between the NumPy and SciPy routines for diagonalization of Hermitian matrices and I got these times on a 6 physical cores machine:

[image]

I am observing that for 8000x8000 matrices this scales to~0.8 minutes and I need to repeat the process 50000 times. Is there something I am missing here or are these actually the performance times? Overall, this all looks very slow specially if this needs to be repeated several times. In fact, on a 30 core machine, I observe little performance gain. I am using the Python3.8 under Anaconda distribution so this is linked against the MKL.

Here is the example code

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyt
from time import time


t_ls = []
d_ls = np.array([100, 500, 1000,2000,4000])

for N in d_ls:

    A =np.random.rand( N,N ) + 1j*np.random.rand( N,N )    
    A = 0.5*( A + np.conj(A.T) ) 
       
    ts = time()    
    evals, evecs = np.linalg.eigh( A )
    t_np  = time()-ts
   

    ts = time()    
    evals2, evecs2 = scipy.linalg.eigh( A )
    t_sp  = time()-ts
    
    t_ls.append(np.array([t_np, t_sp]))
    
t_ls = np.array(t_ls)

pyt.plot( d_ls, t_ls[:,0], marker='s' )
pyt.plot( d_ls, t_ls[:,1], marker='^')
pyt.xlabel("N")
pyt.ylabel("time(secs)")
pyt.legend(["NumPy", "SciPy"])
pyt.show()
```

**USING SVD AND MP PARALELLIZATION**

Going through some of the comments in the post, I have tried SVD of the matrix and multiprocessing. I all cases I still see the serialized approach with NumPy eigh is the most efficient one; here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyt
from time import time

import psutil


def f_mp_pool(*args):
     
    N = args[0]
        
    A =np.random.rand( N,N ) + 1j*np.random.rand( N,N )    
    A = 0.5*( A + np.conj(A.T) ) 
    
    evals, evecs = np.linalg.eigh(A)
    
    return evals, evecs


nreps = 100
N     = 700


ts = time()

for n in range(nreps):
    
    A =np.random.rand( N,N ) + 1j*np.random.rand( N,N )    
    A = 0.5*( A + np.conj(A.T) ) 
    
    res = np.linalg.eigh(A)
    

print("serialized:", time()-ts)

#use svd

import scipy.linalg

ts = time()
for n in range(nreps):
    res = scipy.linalg.svd( A, full_matrices=True, check_finite=False  ) 
    
print("SVD:", time()-ts)    

import multiprocessing as mp

nproc   = psutil.cpu_count(logical=False)-1
mp_pool = mp.Pool(processes=nproc)

args_ls = [ (N,) for n in range(nreps) ]

ts = time()
res = mp_pool.starmap( f_mp_pool, args_ls )
print("parallel:", time()-ts)
```

Comment: Not surprised that you're seeing little speed up regardless of number of cores as you are doing all the processes serially ie one after the other. To really leverage multiple cores then have a look at [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)

Comment: But I always thought that multiprocessing something that is using all threads ( i.e. due to the MKL ) is not going to make any benefits. So, if I have 30 cores and I paralellize as you are suggesting, setting the number of threads to 2 for each launched process, wouldn't this be even slower?

Comment: This looks like a good use case for Numba, Cython or even JAX's vmap.

Comment: How is Numba helping with diagonalization ? Isn't it just wrapping the whole NumPy routine? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57603502/can-numba-accelerate-numpy-functions-that-are-already-vectorized

Comment: Why not just run `SVD` instead of `ED`?

Comment: I have tried using SVD and it does not seem to be faster; additionally one needs to take the square for the eigenvalues etc...

Comment: hmm I keep getting a run time error when your code enters the `multiprocessing` part

Comment: Can you specify which error? The minimal reproducible code works fine on my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pytorch](https://pytorch.org/) will b faster, and if you have GPU it can also take advantage of that, however not so much because the QR iteration is not good for parallel computation. I have a potential solution to accelerate that part on GPUs but I never actually implemented it.

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg
import torch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from time import time

t_ls = []
d_ls = np.array([100, 500, 1000,2000,4000])

for N in d_ls:

    A =np.random.rand( N,N ) + 1j*np.random.rand( N,N )    
    A = 0.5*( A + np.conj(A.T) ) 

#  skipping numpy, it is slow here, you may put it back if you want
#     ts = time()    
#     evals, evecs = np.linalg.eigh( A )
#     t_np  = time()-ts
   

    ts = time()    
    evals2, evecs2 = scipy.linalg.eigh( A )
    t_sp  = time()-ts
    
    # When using CPU torch will use intra operation
    # parallelism, so if you care about latency
    # this is better than using multiprocessing
    A_cpu = torch.as_tensor(A)
    ts = time()
    evals3, evecs3 = torch.linalg.eigh(A_cpu)
    t_cpu = time() - ts;
    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        # Using GPU will give a significant speedup for some
        # operations, I guess the 
        A_gpu = A_cpu.to('cuda')
        torch.cuda.synchronize()
        ts = time()
        evals4, evecs4 = torch.linalg.eigh(A_gpu)
        torch.cuda.synchronize()
        t_gpu = time() - ts;
    else:
        t_gpu = np.nan #if you don't have GPU let's skip this part
    t_ls.append(np.array([np.nan, t_sp, t_cpu, t_gpu]))
    print(t_ls[-1])

t_ls = np.array(t_ls)

plt.plot( d_ls, t_ls[:,0], marker='s' )
plt.plot( d_ls, t_ls[:,1], marker='^')
plt.plot( d_ls, t_ls[:,2], marker='+')
plt.plot( d_ls, t_ls[:,3], marker='d')
plt.xlabel("N")
plt.ylabel("time(secs)")
plt.legend(["NumPy", "SciPy", "PyTorch CPU", "PyTorch GPU"])
```

My plot
[image]

Comment: This look like a great improvement. I was recently reading about Torch and indeed just tried the normal approach, but the GPU improves performance considerably! Something I also noted with the multiprocessing parallelization is that setting the number of threads of MKL equal to 1 seems to make things quite faster; each process is then bounded to a single CPU.

Comment: If you want to compute for multiple matrices of the same size simultaneously you may consider stacking them, pytorch works with a batch of matrices. I know that for low dimensions it does not help a lot but maybe for your use case.