Diagonalising matrices that are too large for gpu memory
I want to diagonalise matrices which are too large for the amount of memory available on the gpu. I am interested in any approaches that would allow me to gain some speed up over just diagonalising the same matrix on a cpu. I need to compute all of the eigenvalues and eigenvectors
For example I have a 55296 x 55296 matrix and a gpu with 80 GB of memory. I am currently using cupy in python and when I try to diagonalise the matrix I get the error:
cupy.cuda.memory.OutOfMemoryError: Out of memory allocating 73,387,745,792 bytes (allocated so far: 48,922,804,736 bytes)
A minimal example of the python code I am running is:
from cupy import linalg
import cupy as cp
import numpy as np

n = 55296

A = np.random.rand(n,n)
A = 0.5*(A+A.T)

lambdas, Ut = (linalg.eigh(cp.asarray(A)))
lambdas = cp.asnumpy(lambdas)
Ut = cp.asnumpy(Ut)

print("Diagonalised successfully")

This example is for a dense matrix but the matrix I have contains some sparsity and can  be diagonalised using less memory on the cpu via employing scipy.linalg.eig_banded. If there were a way to exploit this on the gpu that would also be of interest to me.

Are you just asking someone here to write you a solution? That's too broad a question for StackOverflow. If you have tried a specific approach and ran into problems, please share your code and ask a more specific question. If you're asking for libraries or frameworks that solve this problem, that's also off topic for SO. Please pick a solution that's out there and ask about problems implementing it.

@Grismar I am not asking for a specific solution per se but rather what approach one would use to get around these kinds of memory issues, i.e. options in cupy to make it share memory with the cpu, alternative diagonalisation routines or options. If you believe this is too general a question for SO please could you suggest an appropriate forum to post this issue to?

Someone may want to vote this as a duplicate - I only found it after voting to close for some other reason https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557067/large-matrix-multiplication-on-gpu

@Grismar Matrix diagonalisation is a lot more complicated than matrix multiplication so I don't see how this is a duplicate of the post you linked to

I'm running into the same issue, were you able to find a solution?

@LucasBaldo Not yet. For my purpose I might be able to get away with using single precision, but this obviously isn't a general solution. Alternatively I had thought about trying to use the single precision eigenvectors to help reduce the cost of the double precision diagonalisation on the cpu, but I haven't had time to test whether/how helpful this would be.

Do you need your eigenvalues to be exact? If not, you can search the roots of the characteristic polynomial with whatever numeric method.
In any case, if I were you, I would look for the different available algorithms (see here for example) and implement them one by one until it works (or not). There may already be Python packages for most of them: have a look at this list.

I need all the eigenvalues and eigenvectors as accurately as they would be if calculated using scipy.linalg.eigh. Implementing my own algorithm is not viable unless it involves primarily making use of existing packages available within python

OK. Have you looked for those packages? You may try pytorch: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72270450/full-diagonalization-numpy-vs-scipy

I am not sure how pytorch could help unless it has options that will allow me to share memory with the cpu, I couldn't find any such options reading the documentation for eigh
